# How do I get indices of values where function startswith() is true?

Tags: python, list, indexing, startswith

How do I get the indices of the value where the function "startswith()" is true?

For example: say I have a list `list = ['gene1' , 'gene2' , '0.3', '', '2.3','','0.4']`.

I want to print the value and the index of that value for gene 1 and gene 2 if the float starts with "0.".

Right now I have :

```
s = line.rstrip("\r\n").split(',')
e = [a.replace(" ", "") for a in s]
for i in e:
    if i.startswith("0."):
        print "e[0],e[1], i
```

But that gives me just 1 value and the 2 genes.

I would like to print:

`gene1, gene2, 2, 0.3, 6, 0.4`

where 2 is the index where 0.3 occurs, and 6 is the index where 0.4 occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension and `enumerate`:

```
indices = [index for index, s in enumerate(e) if s.startswith("0.")]
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider `[(i, s) for i, s in enumerate(e) if s.startswith("0.")]`

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you have two options. The first one, having a variable to know the index you are in right now:

```
s = line.rstrip("\r\n").split(',')
e = [a.replace(" ", "") for a in s]
j=0
for i in e:
    if i.startswith("0."):
        print j
    print i
```

The other, is changing the way you iterate:

```
s = line.rstrip("\r\n").split(',')
e = [a.replace(" ", "") for a in s]
j=0
for i in range(len(e)):
    if e[i].startswith("0."):
        print i
    print e[i]
```

This doesn't print the commas, but that should be easy to add, as i am not sure you wanted the commas or those were just a way to show what you wanted.